# What can cause a review to be 'invalidated'?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Today I close voted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50555925/5468463) as off-topic for the lack of MCVE. I saw close(1) was displayed. 
Later on, the question was closed, however I am unable to see my name in the closing list.
I checked the question [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50555925/timeline) and it says that a (probably mine) close vote was invalidated. I am also unable to find that close vote in my profile vote list.
This is first time I see it.

What could cause invalidation?

Comment: Looks to me like you accidentally clicked "flag" instead of "close".  That would trigger a review, one is indeed [on record](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19850369).  Got cancelled when it got closed the normal way about an hour later by 5 other users clicking close. Not actually sure, like you I have far too much rep to ever consider the "flag" option useful

Comment: Would you add a link to the timeline page to this? I wonder if, like me, not everyone knows about it.

Comment: @Hans I think flags are auto converted to close?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems that your close vote was not recorded at all, not even a flag (mods can see flags and close votes in the post timeline). The "invalidated" here means that the review wasn't completed in the Close Votes queue before the question was closed.

Only reviews can be invalidated due to a change of post status (closed/deleted/locked).

You can retract/withdraw your own close vote though, but that didn't happen in this case. A list of your own close votes can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes *(only viewable by yourself)*

Comment: By the way, @SamuelLiew, is "invalidated" for close reviews similar to "aged away" for flags? (i.e.: cases where the review is neither approved nor denied, but the review ceases anyway?)

Comment: @Cœur No, aged away (close votes) means there aren't enough voters voting to close the question. Invalidated (review) means the review is no longer valid as it has since been closed/deleted/edited/locked.

Comment: @Vega well that's really weird then, because it seems that this close vote isn't recorded as well. Do you have any issues with your internet connection?

Comment: Please edit additional info into your question, I'll tag it as a bug report then (you can also unaccept the answer)

Comment: This does look like a bug. It happened to me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44090048/2751851). Note note the review invalidation right at midnight yesterday in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44090048/timeline) (cc @Vega ).